# How do I downgrade / install a specific version of jspm?

Tags: javascript, jspm, systemjs

I upgraded to --latest but want to downgrade to a specific version due to compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the version number like so.

`npm install jspm@1.0.0`